# How to use something like "named parameters" with arrays?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, named-parameters

If something is being passed into a method as object[] myparams, each element needs to be accessed as myparams[0], myparams[1], etc.

Is there some way to provide more meaning to each index rather than just a number?  Something perhaps similar to named parameters, which I know don't work for arrays.

For example:

employeeid = myparams[1];
employeeFirstName = myparams[4];
employeeAddress = myparams[6];

You would have to know that indexes 1, 4, 6 actually refer to those values.

As an additional note, object[] is bound by an interface so there isn't a way to switch out the type.

Comment: You can always do `myVarArgMethod("first-name", "Joe", "last-name", "Shmoe", "dob", new DateTime(2001, 1, 1))`

Comment: Are these downvotes automatic via bots?  They happen almost immediately. Doesn't seem human. stackoverflow needs to fix that.

Comment: I seriously doubt that there are downvoting bots around. It is more likely that some of the viewers of this question didn't understand what you are asking about, and decided to express their disapproval through a vote. I've seen this happen; SO is not going to pay attention as long as it's not a fraud.

Comment: Ok.  Guess I don't see the value in the voting process than.  The answer provided did two things - let me know it is likely the only way and provided a solution.

Comment: It's a good answer, yes. I don't think the voters took their time to decide. I think it's on OK question, so I'll upvote it :)

Comment: @4thSpace Nope. It's automatic people that downvote stuff.

Comment: At moderators, hope I've clarified the question better to remove the hold.  Not sure what that means for all the downvotes.  Thanks @dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use key-value collection (i.e `Dictionary`, `HashSet`) rather than pure array of objects to achieve desired effect.